# A group $G$ whose automorphism group contains a subgroup isomorphic to $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, automorphism-group

The problem is to find a non-trivial group $G$ whose automorphism group contains a subgroup isomorphic to $G$.

I know that $\operatorname {Aut} S_3\simeq S_3$, so the first idea is to prove this. $S_3$ acts on itself by left multiplication, and this action is faithful. This gives an injective group homomorphism $S_3\to \operatorname {Perm} S_3$ from $S_3$ to the group of permutations on the set $S_3$. At this point, I have two questions:

- Is $\operatorname {Perm} S_3$ the same as $\operatorname {Aut} S_3$ (if so, in what sense)? $\operatorname {Aut} S_3$ is the group of isomorphisms from $S_3$ to $S_3$, and it's not evident for me that they are "the same".
- I guess it suffices to show (apart from the above) that $\operatorname {Perm} S_3$ has order $6$. How do I do this?

Comment: To answer the question in the title: Suppose $Z(G)=1$. Then what does the inner automorphism group look like? (Note that $Z(S_3)=1$)

Comment: @user538518: Consider $n > 3$. Then, $Aut(A_n)$ contains $S_n$ as a subgroup and so $A_n$ via $A_n \subseteq S_n$.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to the question in your post: take $G$ with trivial center, then $G/Z(G)=G \cong Inn(G)$ is a subgroup of $Aut(G)$. So $S_3$ is a good example.

Answer (score 1):

No. A permutation of $S_3$ (i.e., of its underlying set) is not an automorphism of $S_3$. For example, every automorphism of a group leaves the neutral element fixed - and left multiplication won't (except in the trivial case).

However, note that $S_3$ has exactly three elements of order $2$ and any automorphism of the group $S_3$ must map elements of order $2$ to elements of order $2$. Can you exploit this fact (and that  $S_3$ is generated by its elements of order $2$) to see how $\operatorname{Aut}S_3\cong S_3$?

---

By the way, with $G=1$, youÄd also have $\operatorname{Aut} G\cong G$.

Comment: I chose the action of $S_3$ on itself randomly. It seems I should have chosen the action by conjugation. In such a case, is $\operatorname{Perm} S_3$ "the same" as $\operatorname{Aut} S_3$? (And what is the meaning of "same"?)

For your hint with orders, I'm not sure how to use it.